# Click on dynamic radio button with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Dynamic radio button:

```
outerHTML = '<label class="Radio-label" for="isCoverSong-e1464493-87d1-434a-97ba-1e8c299b28255-true"><div>Cover song<!----><!----></div></label>'
```

I successfully selected `Radio-label`:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('Radio-label').click()
```

How to select the beginning `'isCoverSong-'` AND the end `'-true'` of the `outerHTML`?

Comment: you have given the code under `With Selenium I want to process it like this :` . what happens if you use that code ? what error are you faciing?

Comment: This code uses css selectors for `css_original` and `css_cover` which changes dynamically and does not include `isCoverSong-` and `-true` at the end of the string.

Comment: @User This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks. That was interesting. I shortened the question to specify the problem.